# Python - Searching input variable in csv file

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to develop a code where if the input variable is in the csv file, the programa should print "Encontrei" (portuguese word for "found") and if not , print ("Não encontrei"). However, this isn´t working, in the input I'm wrighting a word that I know it´s in the csv file, but I´m always getting: "Não encontrei". I tryed 2 different approaches and I´m getting the same result.

1st code:

```
def pilar():
    pilar = input("Perfil do pilar:")
    csv_file=csv.reader(open(r"C:\Users\tomas\Documents\ISEP\5º Ano\TESE\PROGRAMA\PERFIS.csv"))
    
    for row in csv_file:
        if pilar in csv_file:
            print("Pilar: ", pilar)
        else:
            print("Não encontrei")
pilar()
```

2nd code:

```
import csv

with open(r"C:\Users\tomas\Documents\ISEP\5º Ano\TESE\PROGRAMA\PERFIS.csv") as perfis:
    csv_dict_reader = csv.DictReader(perfis)
    
    for row in perfis:
        pilar = input("Pilar: ")
        if pilar in perfis:
            print("Encontrei")
        else:
            print("Não encontrei")
```

Comment: You posted same question 3 times.

Comment: Still looking for help

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
for row in csv_file:
    if pilar in csv_file:
```

To this:

```
for row in csv_file:
    if pilar in row:
```

Comment: Hello. If I do this, the program prints "Não encontrei" for every row.